# Pandas-profiling error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'profile_report'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-profiling

I wanted to use pandas-profiling to do some eda on a dataset but I'm getting an error : AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'profile_report'

I have created a python script on spyder with the following code :

```py
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling
data_abc = pd.read_csv('abc.csv')
profile = data_abc.profile_report(title='Pandas Profiling Report')
profile.to_file(output_file="abc_pandas_profiling.html")
```

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'profile_report'

Comment: Same issue here, saw a ticket that was closed but only identifies there is a problem
https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/issues/201

Answer (score 5):

The `df.profile_report()` entry point is available from v2.0.0. [soln from here](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/issues/183)

Did you install pandas-profiling via pip or conda?

use :  `pip install -U pandas-profiling`  to solve this and restart your kernel

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the team hasn't updated the pip or conda installations yet (described [here](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/issues/183)). If you installed using one of these, try this for the time being.

```
profile = pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(df)
print(profile)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for those who want to use the latest version:

1. Run `pip uninstall pandas_profiling` from anaconda prompt (given you're using Spyder, I'd guess this would be your case) / or command prompt
2. Run `pip install https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/archive/master.zip`

If you're using something like a Jupyter Notebook/Jupyter Lab, be sure to restart your kernel and re-import your packages.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I just used this command to uninstal the package that I installed with Anaconda3, and launched pip install pandas_profiling: I got the last release 2.8.0 and is running - Thx

Answer (score 1):

For the those using google colabs, the profiling library is outdated, hence use the command below and restart the runtime

```
! pip install https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/archive/master.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I found was that the python script I made is getting executed from the command prompt and giving the correct output but the code is still giving an error in Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the version of the pandas-profiling does not work for me and I installed 2.8.0 version and it work for me.

```
!pip install pandas-profiling==2.8.0
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling as pp
df = pd.read_csv('/content/sample_data/california_housing_train.csv')
profile = df.profile_report(title = "Data Profiling Report")
profile.to_file("ProfileReportTest.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above worked, can you check by setting the encoding to unicode_escape in read_csv? It may be due to one of your columns

```
 encoding = 'unicode_escape'
```

Answer (score 0):

### My solution

For me installation via pip was giving errors, therefore I installed it via conda from [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pandas-profiling).

### Code Example

And here is the code example to use profile report:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport

data_abc = pd.read_csv('abc.csv')
profile = ProfileReport(data_abc, minimal=True)
profile.to_file("abc_pandas_profiling.html")
```

### To read the html file I used the following code

```
df = pd.read_html("abc_pandas_profiling.html")
print(df[0])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try in conda environment

```
!pip install --user pandas-profiling
import pandas_profiling
data.profile_report()
```